# How to execute system commands with a button press on a HTML file?

Tags: python, html, raspberry-pi

I have a website on my local server and I like to execute system commands on my local server with a button press in the html file that is displayed. Is there a way to either execute system commands like `gpio write 0 1` or to run python scripts? And how can I get the output of a system command as a string, like `/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp| egrep "[0-9.]{4,}" -o` output e.g. `44.4`?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1):

You will have to a webserver with some kind of server-side script. There's lots of ways you can do this. If you know PHP, that may be easiest. If you want to use python check out [uwsgi](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/).

[Here](https://github.com/korylprince/pyURLShortener) is a pretty simple project I wrote with uwsgi that might help you get started if you go that route. I found a lot of the examples didn't help a lot, so you might have some luck with that code.

**Edit**: Actually, uwsgi on the pi is a pretty old version, and it does some weird things on ARM if you try to compile it.

I created a proof of concept for you [here](https://github.com/korylprince/PiCommand) using [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) instead. Just follow the instructions under the Installing section.

Comment: OK, I installed uwsgi on my Pi, but how can I run python scripts with the press of a button on the html file?